# Calculate number of match in array Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array, and need to find how many matches of a string are.

```
    Array = ['car','road','car','ripple'];

    Array.forEach(function(element) {
      // Here for every element need to see how many there are in the same array.
      // car = 2
      //road = 1
//...
    }, this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#countBy) method for that. You got an object, where keys - it strings in your array and values - the number of occurrences for the appropriate string.

```js
var arr = ['car','road','car','ripple'];

console.log(_.countBy(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla JS you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var array = ['car','road','car','ripple'];

var result = array.reduce(function(r, str) {
  r[str] = (r[str] || 0) + 1;

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```